# Pandas creating extra (duplicated) index after groupby and nlargest

Tags: pandas, indexing, group-by, duplicates

I tried to find the largest N element of each row in a Pandas Dataframe using the `stack().groupby().nlargest().unstack()` chain. However, sometimes the original index get duplicated. Other times it doesn't. This inconsistency in behavior causes subsequent processing very hard. Does anyone know what triggers the difference, and how to force consistency?

For example, here is a case where the index `[x y z]` is duplicated at the end:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,8,9], 'B':[0,np.nan,5], 'C':[2, 10, np.nan]}, index='x y z'.split())
>>> df
     A    B     C
x  NaN  0.0   2.0
y  8.0  NaN  10.0
z  9.0  5.0   NaN
>>> df.stack().groupby(level=0).nlargest(1).unstack()
       A     C
x x  NaN   2.0
y y  NaN  10.0
z z  9.0   NaN
```

whereas in this case it is not:

```
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,np.nan,9], 'B':[0,np.nan,np.nan], 'C':[np.nan, 10, np.nan]}, index='x y z'.split())
>>> df1
     A    B     C
x  NaN  0.0   NaN
y  NaN  NaN  10.0
z  9.0  NaN   NaN
>>> df1.stack().groupby(level=0).nlargest(1).unstack()
     A    B     C
x  NaN  0.0   NaN
y  NaN  NaN  10.0
z  9.0  NaN   NaN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is the paramter `dropna=False` in your `.stack()` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,8,9], 'B':[0,np.nan,5], 'C':[2, 10, np.nan]}, index='x y z'.split())
df.stack(dropna=False).groupby(level=0).nlargest(1).unstack()
```

Output:

```
       A     C
x x  NaN   2.0
y y  NaN  10.0
z z  9.0   NaN
```

And

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':[np.nan,np.nan,9], 'B':[0,np.nan,np.nan], 'C':[np.nan, 10, np.nan]}, index='x y z'.split())
df1.stack(dropna=False).groupby(level=0).nlargest(1).unstack()
```

Output:

```
       A    B     C
x x  NaN  0.0   NaN
y y  NaN  NaN  10.0
z z  9.0  NaN   NaN
```